# Proof of Simplex Method, Adjacent CPF Solutions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I was looking at justification as to why the simplex method runs and the basic arguments seem to rely on the follow:

i)The optimal solution occurs at some vertex of the feasible region (CPF points)

ii) There are a finite number of CPF solutions.

iii)If we are at a CPF solution and any adjacent CPF solution has no better value then our solution is optimal.

I'm good with the first two, however I'm unsure how to prove the third part and can find no proof of it.

I can see how to approach it and I believe that the proof will rest on the convexity of the feasible region. I'm just unsure how to prove this is full generality.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "The proof will rest on the convexity of the feasible region" and on the linearity of the objective function. Starting from a given vertex you can move to any direction, say x, between the edges that connect this vertex and the two adjacent vertices (due to convexity). Write any x as a convex combination of points on these edges (f.e. the two vertices) and then use the linearity of the objective function to prove that if its value is no better in any of these points then there is no direction (within the feasible area) to which you can improve it.

Comment: @stefanos yeah i was kind of wondering how exactly to go about showing this though?

Comment: @hmmmm did you ever find a good explanation for this?